# kotlin : error while parsing a date withe GMT+01:00 as a timezone

Tags: android, date, kotlin, parsing, calendar

I'm parsing a String that has a date format into a variable of type date.  When I ran the code in the emulator it worked fine because the time zone was UTC. Once I tried to run it on my phone it didn"t work because the time zone is GMT+01:00 as you can see in the error below

> Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Feb 01 22:55:22 GMT+01:00 2021"

And here is the code withe the problem

```
 val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
 val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH)
 cal.time = sdf.parse(reminderdate)
```

Your help would be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to try this:
`SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);`